# bootstrap for adding button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, bootstrap-4, haml

```
<th><button type="button" id="selectAll" >Select All</button></th>
```

I have to convert the above code to bootstrap kind of syntax which is to be placed in haml file. Can someone please help me to do that as I am new to bootstrap and haml.
Thanks

Comment: This link could help you https://html2haml.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
%th
  %button.btn.btn-primary#selectAll{type: "button"}
    Select All
```

This will produce :

```
<th>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="selectAll" type="button">
    Select All
  </button>
</th>
```